# Redshift update min date with join

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I want to update the `fact` table and set the `init_date` field equal to the earliest date in the `staging` table where the `sk_c_id, sk_p_id and lot fields` in `staging` match the row being updated in `fact`.

`company` and `product` tables will have to be joined on as well

Example For Lot 88, the following startdate were found : March 7, March 8, March 9, March 10 among all serial numbers as part of of this lot. We want to populate March 7 as init_date in fact table for `sk_c_id, sk_p_id, lot`

```
company table
+---------+-------+
| sk_c_id | c_id  |
+---------+-------+
| 1       | q23t  |
| 2       | t66y  |
| 3       | yu76  |
+---------+-------+

product table
+---------+-------+
| sk_p_id | p_id  |
+---------+-------+
| 1       | 1123  |
| 2       | 4765  |
| 3       | 7784  |
| 4       | 9088  |
| 5       | 1007  |
+---------+-------+

staging table
+----+---------+---------+-----+-----+-----------+
| id | c_id    | p_id    | lot | xyz | startdate |..
+----+---------+---------+-----+-----+-----------+
| 1  | q23t    |  1123   | 88  | ..  | 2019-03-07|..
| 2  | q23t    |  1123   | 88  | ..  | 2019-03-08|..
| 3  | q23t    |  1123   | 88  | ..  | 2019-03-09|..
| 4  | yu76    |  9088   | 66  | ..  | 2019-02-08|
| 5  | t66y    |  7784   | 88  | ..  | 2019-03-08|
| 6  | t66y    |  7784   | 66  | ..  | 2019-03-18|
| 7  | q23t    |  1007   | 66  | ..  | 2018-08-08|..
| 8  | q23t    |  1123   | 88  | ..  | 2019-03-10|..
+----+---------+---------+-----+-----+-----------+

fact table
+----+---------+---------+-----+-----------+----------+-----+
| id | sk_c_id | sk_p_id | lot | start_date|init_date | xyz |..
+----+---------+---------+-----+-----------+----------+-----+
| 1  | 1       |    1    | 88  | 2019-03-17|2019-03-08| ..  |..
| 2  | 1       |    1    | 88  | 2019-03-08|2019-03-08| ..  |..
| 3  | 1       |    1    | 88  | 2019-03-09|2019-03-08| ..  |..
| 4  | 3       |    4    | 66  | 2019-02-08|2019-02-08| ..  |
| 5  | 2       |    3    | 88  | 2019-03-08|2019-03-08| ..  |
| 6  | 3       |    3    | 66  | 2019-03-18|2019-02-08| ..  |
| 7  | 1       |    5    | 66  | 2018-08-08|2018-08-08| ..  |..
+----+---------+---------+-----+-----------+----------+-----+
```

This is what I have until now

```
UPDATE fact
SET init_date = (SELECT initdate FROM (
select s.sk_company_id, s.sk_product_id, min(g.startdate) initdate
from fact f, staging g
GROUP BY f.sk_company_id, f.sk_product_id, f.lot
) st 
join dim_md_company c on c.sk_company_id = st.sk_company_id
join staging_product p on p.sk_product_id = st.sk_product_id
```

but this does not seem to work. I have gone over a few questions on stackoverflow but nothing seems to work for me. 
What would be the correct query for it?

Comment: Can you state the requirement in words? For example, is it that you'd like to update the `fact` table and set the `init_date` field equal to the earliest date in the `staging` table where the `sk_c_id`, `sk_p_id` and `lot` fields in `staging` match the row being updated in `fact`? (If so, why are you including `dim_md_company` and `staging_product` in the `UPDATE` command? They don't seem to be required.)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - this is the exact requirement that you stated. I need to join on the table because both the tables do not look at the same column in company/product table. I have changed the example tables to reflect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the goal is to update the `fact` table and set the `init_date` field equal to the earliest `startdate` in the staging table where the `sk_c_id`, `sk_p_id` and `lot` fields in staging match the row being updated in `fact`.

Let's start with getting the minimum `startdate` for a given company, product and lot:

```
SELECT sk_c_id, sk_p_id, lot, MIN(startdate) as min_start_date
FROM staging
JOIN company c USING (c_id)
JOIN product p USING (p_id)
GROUP BY sk_c_id, sk_p_id, lot
```

To test this, we can join it to the `fact` table to see what the final output would look like:

```
SELECT
  f.*,
  s.min_start_date
FROM fact f
JOIN (SELECT sk_c_id, sk_p_id, lot, MIN(startdate) as min_start_date
      FROM staging
      JOIN company c USING (c_id)
      JOIN product p USING (p_id)
      GROUP BY sk_c_id, sk_p_id, lot
     ) s USING (sk_c_id, sk_p_id, lot)
```

The result comes out as:

```
3   1   1   88  2019-03-09  2019-03-07
2   1   1   88  2019-03-08  2019-03-07
1   1   1   88  2019-03-17  2019-03-07
7   1   5   66  2018-08-08  2018-08-08
5   2   3   88  2019-03-08  2019-03-08
4   3   4   66  2019-02-08  2019-02-08
```

Note that these results show `2019-03-07` as the minimum `startdate` for `1, 1, 88`. This differs to your sample output of `2019-03-08`, but I think your sample date was actually wrong.

Then it is a matter of converting it into an `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE fact
SET init_date = min_start_date
FROM (SELECT sk_c_id, sk_p_id, lot, MIN(startdate) as min_start_date
      FROM staging
      JOIN company c USING (c_id)
      JOIN product p USING (p_id)
      GROUP BY sk_c_id, sk_p_id, lot
     ) s
WHERE fact.sk_c_id = s.sk_c_id
  AND fact.sk_p_id = s.sk_p_id
  AND fact.lot     = s.lot
```

Please note that when using `UPDATE` on a row, Amazon Redshift marks the existing row as *Deleted* and creates a new row at the end of the storage area for each column. Thus, the storage becomes fragmented and out of order.

Therefore, it is recommended to perform a `VACCUUM` on the table after performing the `UPDATE`.

It might also be a good idea to take a backup (snapshot) before performing an `UPDATE` in case data becomes unintentionally overwritten.